# Angular2 routing: can't access the data defined in route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to create a breadcrumb component using [this tutorial by Brian Love](http://brianflove.com/2016/10/23/angular2-breadcrumb-using-router/)

It requires you to set a `breadcrumb` key-value pair in your routes `data`:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: "",
    component: RootComponent,
    children: [{
            path: "signin",
            component: SigninComponent,
            data: {
                breadcrumb: "Sign In"
            }
        },
        {
            path: "signup",
            component: SignupComponent,
            data: {
                breadcrumb: "Sign Up"
            }
        },
        {
            path: "",
            component: IndexComponent
        }
    ]
}, ];
```

For my app module, it works as expected.

However, I have a main module which is lazy-loaded after the user logs in from app. This is where I want my breadcrumbs.

For some reason, I'm unable to access the `data` from my lazy-loaded module, thus satisfying this condition in `breadcrumb.component.ts` and breaking the behavior.

```
 if (!child.snapshot.data.hasOwnProperty(ROUTE_DATA_BREADCRUMB)) {
    continue;
}
```

Any ideas why I can't get the data here?

My app-routing module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { TmLoginComponent } from './login/tm-login.component';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { AuthenticationGuard } from './login/authentication-guard';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './404/page-not-found.component';


const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: 'app/main/main.module#MainModule',
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
}, {
    path: 'login',
    component: TmLoginComponent,
}, {
    path: 'home',
    redirectTo: '/',
    pathMatch: 'full',
}, {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
}];


@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

My main routing module (lazy):

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { MainComponent } from './main.component';
import { IndiaComponent } from './india/india.component';
import { MaharashtraComponent } from './india/maharashtra/maharashtra.component';
import { KarnatakaComponent } from './india/karnataka/karnataka.component';
import { PuneComponent } from './india/maharashtra/pune/pune.component';
import { MumbaiComponent } from './india/maharashtra/mumbai/mumbai.component';

const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    data: {
        breadcrumb: 'Main'
    },
    children: [{
            path: 'india',
            component: IndiaComponent,
            data: {
                breadcrumb: 'India'
            },
            children: [{
                    path: 'maharashtra',
                    component: MaharashtraComponent,
                    data: {
                        breadcrumb: 'Maharashtra'
                    },
                    children: [{
                            path: 'pune',
                            component: PuneComponent,
                            data: {
                                breadcrumb: 'Pune'
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            path: 'mumbai',
                            component: MumbaiComponent,
                            data: {
                                breadcrumb: 'Mumbai'
                            }
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    path: 'karnataka',
                    component: KarnatakaComponent,
                    data: {
                        breadcrumb: 'Karnataka'
                    }
                },
            ],
        },

    ]
}, ];

export const mainRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject `ActivatedRoute` to your component and subscribe to `data` property since it's a [BehaviorSubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md):

```
export class MainComponent {

    constructor(private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
        this._activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
            console.log('data: ', data); // => { breadcrumb: 'Main' }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. Using your advice, I can access the data for my `main` route, but the data for the child routes is still undefined.

Comment: Hi. Following the same logic, in order to access the data defined in your child route, you need to inject the ActivatedRoute in the child component.

Comment: Okay, I injected the `ActivatedRoute` in all the child comps, your fuction logs the data correctly from the respective constructors; but I'm still unable to access it using my breadcrumb component.

Comment: It's not currently directly supported to access the activated route data of the other component except for its own. There are some 'hacky' solutions around, this link could be helpful for your use case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38312417/angular2-router-get-route-data-from-url-to-display-breadcrumbs

Comment: The hacky solution is what I'm using :)  Doesn't seem to word for lazy modules