# Angular 2 BreadCrumb:Property 'breadcrumb' does not exist on type

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to implement breadcrumb in Angular 2 and referring the below post https://stackoverflow.com/a/38808735/5327791
But I'm getting the error  **"Property 'breadcrumb' does not exist on type '{ [name: string]: any; }'"** at line- label: route.snapshot.data.breadcrumb.
I see that data is not having breadcrumb property.
Looking badly for help

Comment: The error say that you are trying to get the property 'breadcrumb' of a string. If you show more code (your component and template) maybe we could help.

Comment: @mickdev I'm following the same example which I mentioned and there is and the plunker link is https://plnkr.co/edit/YtJDZlA1mHtjA9ZmMHB3?p=preview

Comment: In `BreadcrumbsComponent`, this line `label: route.snapshot.data.breadcrumb,` get the data provided in the `app.routes.ts` and `app/user/user.routes.ts` files. You should confirm that everything is ok (console log route.snapshot.data for example). Also, you should provide the plunker with your actual code so maybe someone will see what you are missing