# Angular4: passing breadcrumb view components through the router's `data` property

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In my Angular (v4) app, I'm trying to create a breadcrumb module. I found [this S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38808735/5490505) helpful, suggesting I store breadcrumb information in the router's `data` property like so

```
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, data: {breadcrumb: 'home'}}
```

But what I'd like to do is store *a component* in the data property, and then have the breadcrumb module extract and render it. Allowing me to interact with the breadcrumb module like this

```
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, data: {breadcrumb: CustomViewComponent}}
```

Following the angular [Dynamic Component Loader guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html) and a [helpful blog post](https://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-2-dynamically-render-components/), I've attempted to make my breadcrumb rendering component do this:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, AfterViewInit,
  ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

import { MainLogoComponent } from '../my-material/main-logo/main-logo.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-breadcrumbs',
  template: `<div #parent></div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./breadcrumbs.component.scss']
})    
export class BreadcrumbsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  breadcrumbs: Array<any>;
  @ViewChild('parent', {read: ViewContainerRef}) parent: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private router:Router, private route:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .subscribe(event => {  // note, we don't use event
        this.breadcrumbs = [];
        let currentRoute = this.route.root,
            url = '';
        do {
          let childrenRoutes = currentRoute.children;
          currentRoute = null;
          childrenRoutes.forEach(route => {
            if(route.outlet === 'primary') {
              let routeSnapshot = route.snapshot;
              url += '/' + routeSnapshot.url.map(segment => segment.path).join('/');
              this.breadcrumbs.push({ 
                label: route.snapshot.data.breadcrumb,
                url:   url });
              currentRoute = route;
            }
          })
        } while(currentRoute);
      })
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const logoComponent = this.componentFactoryResolver
      .resolveComponentFactory(this.breadcrumbs[0]); // at the moment just using breadcrumbs[0] for simplicity
    this.parent.createComponent(logoComponent);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, it appears that the route data property cannot / will not store a component. Delving into the debug console, the data property gets saved as `{data: {breadcrumb: }}`

If anyone knows of a way to make this code work, or has a suggestion for a better way to achieve my goal of building a breadcrumbs component that consumes other view components, I would ***greatly*** appreciate it!!

PS: If I skip the `data` property, and just manually ask the breadcrumb component to add a `MainLogoComponent` to the page like so:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const logoComponent = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MainLogoComponent);
    this.parent.createComponent(logoComponent);
  }
```

It works

And, for completeness, the code for the associated route.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'calendar',
    data: {
      breadcrumb: MainLogoComponent
    },
    canActivate: [ AuthGuard ],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: CalendarComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

UPDATE

Here is the relevant NgModule:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MyMaterialModule
  ],
  exports: [
    BreadcrumbsComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [BreadcrumbsComponent, MainLogoComponent],
  declarations: [BreadcrumbsComponent] // MainLogoComponent is declared in MyMaterialModule
})
export class BreadcrumbsModule { }
```

Comment: Have you tried to move your code from `ngAfterViewInit` to `subscribe` handler?

Comment: So the dynamic loading of components needs to be done during the `ngAfterViewInit()` callback (it can't be done during `ngOnInit()`). I have tried moving all of the `init` work into `ngAfterViewInit` and then also trying to create the components inside the `subscribe` handler. It produces an error. I was able to get it to produce a "No component factory found for MainLogoComponent" error (indicating that the `data` property wasn't empty. But examining the `MainLogoComponent` inside `data`: its just something like ~`function MainLogoComponent() {}`. Not an object like I was expecting.

Comment: `No component factory found for MainLogoComponent` means you have to add this component to `entryComponents` array

Comment: It is part of the `entryComponents` array. And the fact that I *can* successfully load the `MainLogoComponent` dynamically, just not using the routes `data` property (see the PS in the question), indicates to me that I have correctly set up the module.

Comment: Have you tried `this.breadcrumbs[0].label`?

Comment: Open plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/GJW01PW1Igxbh44pRYJO?p=preview and go to calendar page

Comment: @yurzui, wow! It certainly looks like you got the idea working. Let me look at this a bit more then I'll update with findings. And regardless, THANKS for the help!!! I *really* appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I got it working as I wanted it to work (a BIG thank you to @yurzui for *taking the time* to create a plnkr showing it should work, in concept!!!!! That REALLY ***REALLY*** helped and I'm incredibly greatful!!). I'm still not exactly sure where I was doing wrong, but I created a new app to make the breadcrumbs module, got it working, and then ported it to my real app. One probable issue, I've discovered, is that `ng serve` seems to occationally miss recompiling files I've changed (or perhaps my browser is caching errors). Several times now, the compiler has spit out errors concerning variables I've deleted and when I restart `ng serve` (without changing anything) the errors go away. A warning for other people troubleshooting problems (though maybe it's isolated to my dev setup).

Here is the final, working *breadcrumbs* code (note, if you're trying to replicate my method also read through the info / links in the original question).

```js
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

import { BreadDividerComponent } from './bread-divider/bread-divider.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-breadcrumbs',
  template: `
    <div #breadContainer></div>
    <div #iconContainer></div>
    <div #lastBreadContainer></div>`
})
export class BreadcrumbsComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  breadcrumbs: Array<any>;
  storedBreadcrumbs: Array<Component>;
  @ViewChild('breadContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) breadContainer: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('iconContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) iconContainer: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('lastBreadContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) lastBreadContainer: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private router: Router) { }
  
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.router.events
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .subscribe(event => {
        // Reset variables and clear breadcrumb component on view change
        this.breadcrumbs = [];
        this.storedBreadcrumbs = [];
        this.breadContainer.clear();
        this.iconContainer.clear();
        this.lastBreadContainer.clear();

        // Drill down through child routes
        let currentRoute = this.router.routerState.snapshot.root.firstChild;
        if (currentRoute) {
          do {
            this.breadcrumbs.push(currentRoute.data.breadcrumb);
            currentRoute = currentRoute.firstChild;
          } while (currentRoute)
        }

        // Because each route's home path is actually itself a child route
        // e.g. { path: 'two', children: [ { path: '', component: ... } ] }
        if (this.breadcrumbs.length === 2 
          && this.breadcrumbs[0] === this.breadcrumbs[1]) {
            this.breadcrumbs = [this.breadcrumbs[0]];
        }

        this.breadcrumbs.forEach((breadcrumb, index, array) => {
          if (array.length > 1) {
            if (index < array.length - 1) {
              const breadFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver
                .resolveComponentFactory(breadcrumb);
              this.storedBreadcrumbs.push(this.breadContainer.createComponent(breadFactory));

              const iconFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver
                .resolveComponentFactory(BreadDividerComponent);
              this.storedBreadcrumbs.push(this.iconContainer.createComponent(iconFactory));
            } else {
              const breadFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver
                .resolveComponentFactory(breadcrumb);
              this.storedBreadcrumbs.push(this.lastBreadContainer.createComponent(breadFactory));
            }
          } else {
            const breadFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver
              .resolveComponentFactory(breadcrumb);
            this.storedBreadcrumbs.push(this.lastBreadContainer.createComponent(breadFactory));
          }
        });
      });
  }
}
```

Breadcrumb view components are passed through the router's data property, like so:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'calendar',
    data: {
      breadcrumb: CalendarBreadcrumbComponent,
      menu: CalendarMenuComponent
    },
    canActivate: [ AuthGuard ],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'events',
        data: {
          breadcrumb: EventsBreadcrumbComponent
        },
        component: EventsComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'events'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I also use this strategy to build my app's menu. Here's an example of a breadcrumb view component

```js
import { Component, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer  } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar-breadcrumb',
  templateUrl: './calendar-breadcrumb.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar-breadcrumb.component.scss']
})
export class CalendarBreadcrumbComponent {
  // Modify this components parent element so that it is displayed with flexbox
  @HostBinding('attr.style') style = this.sanitizer
    .bypassSecurityTrustStyle('display: flex; flex-direction: row;');

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
}
```

And the associated view file (which, I'm realizing now, really doesn't need its own file...)

```html
<md-icon>event</md-icon><h3>Calendar</h3>
```